# Django rest framework Custom User model with token error

Tags: django, django-models

I've tried to use custom user model instead of default user.

My Django project structure is below.

- Project name : project_rest
- App name : app_rest

To make it happen, I refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

[settings.py]

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_rest.User'`

[models.py]

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, null=False, max_length=254)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

[serializers.py]

```
from app_rest.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

[views.py]

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app_rest.serializers import UserSerializer
from app_rest.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

[urls.py]

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from app_rest import views
from rest_framework import routers
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework.authtoken import views as rest_views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^token-auth/', rest_views.obtain_auth_token),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I seems work properly, But when I delete user, It throws error.

> IntegrityError at /admin/app_rest/user/1/delete/ (1452, 'Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   ('rest'.'django_admin_log', CONSTRAINT
>   'django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id' FOREIGN KEY
>   ('user_id') REFERENCES 'auth_user' ('id'))')

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory. The record you are trying to delete is related to another one by a foreign key and it cannot be deleted as it would break referential integrity.

You need to alter that id with something like ON DELETE CASCADE or its equivalent, or allow the user to be null on the related table (if that's possible).